# PHP and Excel calculation differences

Tags: php, excel

the problem I have is that when making same calculations in PHP and in Excel I get different answers, e.g.:

PHP

```
bcdiv(135.248162939981, 135.582429275152, 15)
```

is equal to `0.997534589571912`

while performing the `135.248162939981 / 135.582429275152` in Excel is equal to `0,997534589570654`

How to solve such issues and to have differences in calculations?

Comment: What your seeing is floating point precision differences in the calculations between PHP and Excel.  I have no idea how to "resolve" the issue, but I know the problem.  I guess the first question would be, whom do you consider correct PHP or Excel?

Comment: I'm considering Excel calculations to be correct.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[`bcdiv`](http://php.net/bcdiv) performs an *arbitrary* precision calculation. Much unlike Excel, which does an ordinary floating point division.

To get a *similar* result in PHP just do it alike:

```
 $r = 135.248162939981 / 135.582429275152;
```

That being said, the results will never be *identical*. Floating point calculations are inexcat by nature, furthered by display variations in programming languages and applications. [http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Precision_(computer_science)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Precision_%28computer_science%29)